# Is there a way to check when a series is highlighted on apache echarts line chart

Tags: angular, echarts, apache-echarts

I'm using the Line Chart type from Apache Echarts in an Angular project and I need to know when a line has entered into the "highlight" or "emphasis" state:

[image]

This state is triggered when hovering on a line & letting the cursor there *(cursor not showing on screenshot)*.

Using the ["highlight" event](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.highlight) from the chart instance does not work because it emits every time you move the cursor anywhere on the graph; and actually, it does not emit when you do the hover & holding.

Using the ZRender object and listening to the "mouseover" event is more accurate as it emits only when you "mouseover" a series line. However, I still don't know when the line has actually entered into the "emphasis" or "highlight" state (when the others are grayed out and the hovered line keeps its color).

```
this.chartInstance.getZr().on('mouseover', (event: any) => {
  console.log(event);

  // can't find anything that can tell me if a series line is highlighted or not.
  console.log((this.chartInstance as any).getModel());
  console.log((this.chartInstance as any).getModel().getSeries());
})
```

Is there a flag on the series data that could tell me if one series (line) is on the "highlight" state?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me. Try not to log the event, instead log params and get the event from there (look at console).

```js
let myChart02 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('echart02'));

myChart02.group = 'myGroup';

myChart02.on('mouseover', (params) => {
  console.log(params);
})

myChart02.setOption(option02);
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/echarts-sync-zoom-only-jzkzh8?file=index.js

Comment: I'll update my question to add more details on what I need. I'm using the line chart type and I need to know when a line has entered into the "highlight" or "emphasis" state. On echarts this happens when you hover a line and keep the mouse pointer there.